# Converting Subselect Queries From SQL Server to DB2 Syntax Order By Clause

Tags: sql-server, database, db2, data-conversion

Currently I'm trying working on a query and trying to figure out a way of how to use the Order By Clause in the DB2 that is not working but is currently working in SQL Server when ran against the DBMS. The SQL Server syntax is below and the query is subqueried and not joined. I have tried different ways to convert the data so it works to pull the result set in DB2 syntax by joining the tables together, tinkering with the tables together with the Order By Clause. The objective is to try and sort the boxNumber column in Ascending order (smallest to largest). Can i get some advice on how to pull resultset successfully without receiving a SQL Error Code that is not a -104 or -206? Is there a certain limitation difference between SQL Server and the DB2 syntax when it comes to the Order By clause?

SQL Server:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT boxNumber FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ORDER.orderId =orderId) AS boxNumber
FROM ORDER
WHERE ((istask = 0 AND historyflag= 0) AND
(orderId IN (SELECT orderId
           FROM PRODUCTS
           WHERE ORDER.orderId = orderId AND [STATUS] = 'AVAIL' OR [STATUS]='INSTOCK')))
ORDER BY (SELECT boxNumber FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ORDER.orderId =orderId);
```

Below are some examples of the code in DB2 that i have been trying to run against:
Example 1:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT boxNumber FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ORDER.orderId =orderId) AS boxNumber
FROM ORDER
WHERE ((istask = 0 AND historyflag= 0) AND
(orderId IN (SELECT orderId
           FROM PRODUCTS
           WHERE ORDER.orderId = orderId AND STATUS = 'AVAIL' OR STATUS='INSTOCK')))
ORDER BY boxNumber;
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDER
WHERE ((istask = 0 AND historyflag = 0)
AND (orderId IN (SELECT orderId
     FROM PRODUCTS prod LEFT JOIN ORDER ord
     ON prod.orderId = ord.orderId
     WHERE STATUS IN ('AVAIL','INSTOCK') ORDER BY prod.boxNumber)))
```

Example 3:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDER
WHERE ((istask = 0 AND historyflag = 0)
AND (orderId IN (SELECT orderId
FROM PRODUCTS prod LEFT JOIN ORDER ord
ON prod.orderId = ord.orderId
WHERE ORDER.orderId = orderId AND STATUS IN ('AVAIL','INSTOCK') ORDER BY prod.boxNumber)))
```

Comment: What's the exact error code and message from the following statement? `SELECT ORDER.*, (SELECT boxNumber FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ORDER.orderId =orderId) AS boxNumber
FROM ORDER
WHERE ((istask = 0 AND historyflag= 0) AND
(orderId IN (SELECT orderId
           FROM PRODUCTS
           WHERE ORDER.orderId = orderId AND STATUS = 'AVAIL' OR STATUS='INSTOCK')))
ORDER BY boxNumber;`

Comment: Sorry for not providing that. the error I kept receiving that were showing in the logs was for SQL -206 orderId is ambiguous and for the SQL -104 error code it was telling me either it was a token issue with a parentheses or the order by for box number was not defined or valid.

Comment: Try this [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=60c85fc1a25def0644a7d9786302ea36) **as is**. It works without any errors. You may modify the statement at the link, provide here your link to updated example, if something still doesn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
    SELECT *,
            (SELECT boxNumber
         FROM PRODUCTS
         WHERE ORDER.orderId = orderId) AS boxNumber
    FROM ORDER
    WHERE istask = 0 AND historyflag= 0
    AND   orderId IN (SELECT orderId
                      FROM PRODUCTS
              WHERE ORDER.orderId = orderId
              AND STATUS = 'AVAIL' OR STATUS = 'INSTOCK')
) as T
ORDER BY boxNumber;
```

If the problem is indeed in the `ORDER BY` clause, that should solve the problem.  It shouldn't be; AFIAK, that clause should accept any `SELECT` column, including a subquery.  (In the future, be sure to include the literal error message with your question.  The person answering your question will likely find it helpful.)

I took the liberty of removing superfluous parentheses and bracket-quotes. Unnecessary punctuation only makes the code harder to read.